# Difference between git fetch <remote> and git fetch <remote> <branch>

Tags: git

I had a remote branch that I was already using and I wanted to update the refs on it, so I typed `git fetch <remote> <branch>` and the branch did not update with the latest refs.  I found I had to use `git fetch <remote>` (without a branch) to get the current remote updates on that branch.  Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git fetch <remote> <branch>` will fetch the single given branch from the given remote and store it in FETCH_HEAD.

`git fetch <remote>` will use the default refspec which is usually configured as `remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` and therefore will fetch all branches and stores them in the corresponding remote branch.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't see the specific (and apparently additional) step that git fetch <remote> is performing over git fetch <remote> <branch> when encountering the specific <branch>.  Do you know what that is?